# Can't force my sprite to move/rotate smoothly

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

**Update:** to not clutter the question with tons of text I've edited and made it simpler.

[Wheel Joint 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelJoint2D.html) is used to rotate a sprite:

[image]

So the issue is that the circle rotates with mirco-glitches/jerks. If you watch carefully you can spot them every 5-10 seconds. And it doesn't matter what type of rigidbodies are used kinematic or dynamic. I would like my circle to rotate more smoothly, how to get it? Or is this the best smoothness you can achieve with Unity? Thank you for any help!

Unity version: 2018.2.0f2.
Full Unity project and APK file can be downloaded **[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rkQMcaOU-5l7859R6zgIH7NG0izTTRmD/view?usp=sharing)**.

Comment: Does it happen in a build too? Sometimes the performance of the editor is not perfect.

Comment: Yes, it even happens when I install game on my android device (.apk file is attached to the question so you can try it). So I don't think it is a computer's/editor's performance issue. Also, I am not moving camera in my game, so seems it is also not a camera issue..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing either you're: 
Rotating and supplying degrees where you should be supplying radians or; 
Reaching a floating-point granularity issue where you're rotating by an ever increasing float value without giving it the 'ol modulus 360 treatment to keep the number of digits low thus precision high.

Good Luck!

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how to do the keeping of digits low? This seems like something I'm also struggling with, similar setup.

Comment: Regarding degrees vs radians - I am rotating sprite using Unity [Wheel Joint 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelJoint2D.html) component, so I am just increasing it's `motorSpeed` property, see code above. Regarding  'keeping the number of digits low' issue - could you please provide code example?

Comment: Imagine you're rotating an object using a float value _val.  Every frame you add .001f to your float _val, ie _val += .001f;  This works and after your float value gets past .360 ie to .361 your program still works.  ( .361 is 'one full rotation + .001' etc.)

The problem occurs when your rotational _val becomes large, ie 100000000.360.  When this happens you might notice that adding .001 to _val doesn't result in the number you expect (10000000.361) and instead leaves you with 10000000.360 again or perhaps 10000000.362.  Your floating point number has lost precision due to it's size.

Comment: Limit the number by doing something like:
_val += .001;
_val = _val % 1;

This will limit the size of your number below 1 and thus limit the dilution of precision that occurs when using BIG floating point numbers that  have SMALL decimal point values.

Comment: Anyway it doesn't resolve my issue, but thanks for the input. I think I need to make some basic optimizations of my project.

Comment: Good idea.  Totally worth the time investment to do root cause analysis and fix the problem after learning more about it.  The only other option is to fumble around and waste time bandage-coding towards the target.  Tried that, would not recommend!